# Hold onto variable value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason, when using a `Select Case` statement in VBA, I seem to be losing my variable value once the statement completes.

For context, I am trying to capture a double click action on two specific cells, in a specific order. The point is for a hidden function, so to run the function a user must first double click on cell `U35`, which should set the `egg` variable to `1`. Then, if the user double clicks on cell `AF35`, AND the `egg` variable is set to `1`, then the function will run.

The problem I am having is that after double clicking cell `U35`, the `egg` variable gets set to `null`, hence the second `Case` statement is never reached.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim egg
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Select Case egg
        Case Is = 0
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("U35")) Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox ("First action captured")
                egg = 1
            End If
        Case Is = 1
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AF35")) Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox ("Second action captured")
                egg = 0
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: *Used to compare two object reference variables.* **Syntax**  `result = object1 Is object2`. From Help. Use `=`.

Comment: `egg` is only visible inside `Worksheet_Activate` - if you want it to be visible inside `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` then make it a global (declared at the top of the module)

Comment: @ACatInLove - see https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php (at the end)

Comment: Can they click `U35`, then any other cell, then `AF35`? Or is it back to back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to globally declare your variable `egg`, out of the macro `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()`, so that it keeps its value even once you get out of the local context.

```
Dim egg As Integer '<-- global declaration (on top of module)
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    'rest of your code
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a global variable, and set it on the Worksheet Activate, and fix the `Select Case` a little:

```
Dim egg As Long
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    egg = 0
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Debug.Print (egg)
    Select Case egg
        Case Is = 0
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("U35")) Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox ("First action captured")
                egg = 1
            End If
        Case Is = 1
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AF35")) Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox ("Second action captured")
               ' Do things here when they're clicked back-to-back
            End If
            egg = 0
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**
"Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick" is unable to recognize "egg" from "Worksheet_Activate" because they are private subs.

There are 2 types of subs in VBA, private and public. There are some exceptions, generally speaking **information inside a private sub cannot be accessed from another sub**.

**Solution(s)**
A) define the variable as a global object
B) define the variable inside the sub it will be used

**A) define the variable as a global object**

```
Public egg as Integer



Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    egg = 0
    'this is not necessary, you can set it inside BeforeDoubleClick
End Sub



Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    *your code*
End Sub
```

**B) define the variable inside the sub it will be used**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim egg as Integer
    egg = 0
    *your code*
End Sub
```